# Does Paxos get run for the first statement or the entire batch?

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to figure out how LWT work in Cassandra with relatively large batches. My use case essentially involves something like:

```
BEGIN BATCH
  UPDATE foo SET generation = 10 WHERE partitionKey = '0' IF generation < 10;
  INSERT INTO ...; --- all inserts here use the same partitionKey
  INSERT INTO ...;
END BATCH
```

The first statement is always a CAS operation using a LWT and the rest of the batch are simple insert statements with no IF clause, though there could be thousands of them. I'm using the first CAS statement to "fence" writers if there are competing writers.

In the steady state, there's only one writer per partition key so contention on these operations should be pretty rare. What I'm wondering is how to reason about performance of these operations? Does Paxos get run once for the first statement or does it run with the entire batch?

I tend to get a lot of exceptions like:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during CAS write query at consistency SERIAL (1 replica were required but only 0
acknowledged the write)
```

Also I read somewhere that LWTs are parallelized by partition key, so if multiple writers to different partition keys would that cause any issues?

The code seems to work most of the time, but after running for a while I get timeouts as seen above. These timeouts also happen if I'm running only a single Cassandra node.

Also any pointers as for what to look for in server logs would be helpful - I don't see any exceptions in the cassandra.log files with INFO log level.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you described doesn't have anything to do with LWT or Paxos. The issue is that you have batched too many mutations together.

I suspect you are misusing batches to bulk-load data. Even for single-partition batches, the disks still need to be able to keep up with writes. This is what is leading to the `WriteTimeoutException` -- the disk is overloaded so the node(s) doesn't respond to the coordinator (itself for single-node clusters) within the write request timeout period.

CQL batches are not an optimisation in the same way as they do in traditional relational databases. You should only batch statements when atomicity is required.

In almost all cases, separate asynchronous writes will always outperform batches. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the response Erick! We are not using it to bulk load, it's important that the entire batch is atomic in that if the first CAS goes through the rest should otherwise none of the writes should go through.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. How is it that you'd be inserting thousands of rows if you're not bulk loading?

Comment: We're buffering writes in our clients to ensure that it happens transactionally with another system in something similar to a 2PC with Cassandra and another system. There can be lots of "uncommitted" state that should only be read by the client until the commit happens, which is why there could be thousands of rows.